# .Net Core Web API on Azure is not providing API endpoints, only default starter page

Tags: c#, azure, .net-core-3.1

I've built a simple "Web API" using .Net Core 3.1. Works great locally, and connects to an Azure SQL database. However, when I publish the API to an Azure App Service, I'm unable to figure out where the API is or why it isn't working. Publish is successful. Azure log stream seems to show that the container starts up successfully. However, I only get the default azure web app page, like it was when I first set up the App Service. I've tried checking port 8080, 8081, 5000, 5001, and even 55546/44311 used in IIS Express locally. There is nothing at those ports. When I go to https://[myapp].azurewebsites.net/api/[myendpoint] I just get a 404. I'm at a complete loss and have spent the entire day trying to figure out why this doesn't just work, considering how perfectly it works locally.

[image: Azure Log Stream]
EDIT: Before the log data above, what I didn't see was that my app container failed to start due to lack of .NET Core SDK. Azure App Services do not include the SDK, only the runtime.

```
2020-06-16T01:20:26.698003315Z   Did you mean to run .NET Core SDK commands? Install a .NET Core SDK from:
2020-06-16T01:20:26.698408243Z       https://aka.ms/dotnet-download
2020-06-16T01:20:26.707756994Z WARNING: Startup command execution failed with exit code 145
2020-06-16T01:20:26.708382837Z Running the default application instead...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I initially posted the question, I did not realize that my app container had not started properly due to lack of .Net Core SDK. After a bit of help from Microsoft, then from a youtuber, because Microsoft didn't know how to fix the issue, I found out that on linux Azure App Services, you must publish the app as a "Self-Contained" deployment and the target being linux-x64. Once I did this and published, all started working.

[image]